# Facing some problems in groupby function for Outlier Removal

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working on a data cleaning project and in this, I have to remove some outliers of `price_per_sqft`.. So I used `groupby` function and by statistic, the formula creates a data frame **without** outliers and `concat` it with the output data frame...

But in the output this type of word returns with the location names so how can I get a clean location name instead of this..?

**Code:**

```
def remove_pps_outliers(df):

    df_out = pd.DataFrame()
    for key, subdf in df.groupby('location'):
        m = np.mean(subdf.price_per_sqft)
        st = np.std(subdf.price_per_sqft)
        reduced_df = subdf[(subdf.price_per_sqft>(m-st)) & (subdf.price_per_sqft<=(m+st))]
        df_out = pd.concat([df_out,reduced_df],ignore_index=True)
    return df_out
df6 = remove_pps_outliers(df5)
df6.head()
```

**Output:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StfjN.png)

How can I get the answer without "1st Phase" or "1st Block" keywords like this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7I2Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

A rudimentary fix would be to just replace the characters you do not want. Luckily in this example, both `'1st Phase '` and `'1st Block '` contain 10 characters so you could use :

`df6['location'] = df6['location'].str.slice_replace(0,10,'')`